# Defining statistical significance under methods: using alpha or p?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, definition, reporting

**Two options:**

> Statistical significance was defined as **alpha = 0.05**, and all tests were 2-sided.

> Statistical significance was defined as **p < 0.05**, and all tests were 2-sided.

**Are both of them correct, meaning that all p-values < 0.05 are considered to be statistically significant?**

Comment: Yes they are equivalent.